# postgres query with current_date is not working

Tags: postgresql

Below is my query in postgres

```
select dns_time,update_time from dns_lookup where update_time=current_date;
```

Here update_time is of type timestamp with time zone.
I have tried this one also.

```
select dns_time,update_time from dns_lookup where update_time like current_date;
```

Then also getting no results.
I have records with current_date values.But it is not showing me any records.How to compare timestamp with time zone value with current_date.please help me
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First: `LIKE` on a date or timestamp column does not make *any* sense.

A `timestamp` contains a time part so a comparison with a plain `date` won't work. You need to remove the time from the timestamp by casting it to a date:

```
where cast(update_time as date) = current_date;
```

Note that this will void the usage of an index on `update_time`. If that is a problem you can create a function based index on that expression.

Comment: works flawlessly!

Answer (score 2):

You might be trying to compare a `timestamp` field with the `Date` field.

Try casting timestamp to Date

```
select dns_time,update_time from dns_lookup where update_time::Date=current_date;
```

Hope this helps.